# How to run validator from javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here is a part of my code:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbRD" runat="server" DataSourceID="RDSqlDataSource" onchange="JSFillDetail();" DataTextField="Описание" DataValueField="ID" Width="188px" Height="200px"/>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtDescriptionRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Описание является обязательным для заполнения" ControlToValidate="txtDescription" />
```

I have a listbox, a textbox and a required field validator on my page. When the user selects something from the listbox, the selected item appears in the textbox using a javascript function. When the page is submitted, the validator reports an error in case the textbox is empty. If after that the user selects something from the listbox, the error message is still displayed, even though the textbox is not empty anymore. How can I make the validator validate the textbox, or even better, to clear the error message from the javascript function that fills the textbox?
Thanks, David

Comment: can u post a snippet of your code it will be easy for us to answer your question

Comment: This is a very unclear question - you'd to well to reword this, and include more information, like what your "validator" is - PHP server-side code, javascript code on another page...what? Best of all would be to include a code snipper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control your page flow with the `Page_ClientValidate()` function and the `Page_Validators` collection:

```
Page_ClientValidate();
var i;
for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++)
{
    if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid)
    {
        //example: call focus on first item that's invalid
        document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate).focus();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. In fact, Page_ClientValidate(); was enough for me, as I knew the page was valid, I just needed to get read of the previous error message.